# Installing GHC on Windows

Tags: haskell, installation, ghc

Using this guide's instructions to install GHC on my Windows 10 instance, I can't follow the first step:

https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.0/docs/html/users_guide/sec-install-windows.html

```
"Download the Installshield setup.exe from the GHC download page haskell.org."
```

Having dowloaded this file from the site linked in that guide, there is no setup.exe.

```
Windows 64-bit (x86_64)
ghc-8.6.2-x86_64-unknown-mingw32.tar.xz (203.8 MB, sig)
This is compatible with Microsoft Windows Vista and later. It also includes 
support for compiling C++ files.
```

I unzip the file to folder "ghc-8.6.2" consisting of folders

```
"bin, doc, lib, mingw, perl"
```

(Yes, I searched for the setup.exe)

Could anyone tell me how I could get to the setup.exe so it will take care of setting up PATH etc?

Comment: Those installation instructions are from 2003 (when GHC 6.0 was released). For something up-to-date, visit https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html and download the "Core" installer available there.

Comment: Instead of *installing* GHC globally on Windows, I recommend using [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org) to compile, run, and develop Haskell code. I've done this on Windows 10 for years, and while not frictionless, it works better than installing the Haskell platform.

Answer (score -2):

You can use chocolatey [1] in which case it's just

`choco install ghc` which will install ghc and Cabal and give you a working environment. It has every version of ghc and Cabal released.

More here https://chocolatey.org/packages/ghc/

[1] https://chocolatey.org

Comment: In my experience, Chocolatey is messy, doesn't provide start menu links, nor WinGHCI, and installs things in obscure places before even attempting to  use regular Windows conventions like C:\Program Files

Comment: Uhmm. Ghc doesn't have a gui. You want a start link to a console application? WinGHCI is also not part of ghc or maintained in the last 10 years. And it doesn't install to program files because the toolchain can't handle paths with spaces. Dos short names which was the workaround haskell platform uses isn't a portable workaround and has performance issues. Furthermore installing to program files will typically eat a large number of characters from the MAX_PATH issue that plagues the gnu toolchains it uses. So yes it doesn't install there for very good reasons.